# What will the ETH inflation rate be after PoS is released?

Tags: proof-of-stake

Has the Proof of Stake emission schedule been decided yet? What will be the rate of inflation? Is 2017 for the end of PoW still the best estimate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Vitalik and Vlad said they want the rate to be very low. Most rewards should come from transaction fees eventually.

Having said that I don't think the PoS staking reward has been set in stone at this point.